# One-to-One Relationship Tables not Linked

Tags: database, ms-access

My one-to-one relationship table in MS Access is not linked in the sense that when I update one the other updates.  Is this supposed to happen?  If I manually update the one table that is linked, it contains the data from the parent table, but it's not doing it as I update the parent.  Is there a way to get this done automatically?  Or do I have to individually add each line?  (btw there is 19,000+ records so far)

Comment: You mean enable cascade updates? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-table-relationships-30446197-4fbe-457b-b992-2f6fb812b58f ... Access supports the Cascade Update Related Fields option. When you enforce referential integrity and choose the Cascade Update Related Fields option, and you then update a primary key, Access automatically updates all fields that reference the primary key.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6mLVHXM7g4

Comment: ***Is this supposed to happen?***  Not by default. ***Is there a way to get this done automatically?*** yes right click on the relationship and enforce referential integrity and then enable cascade update

Comment: I am assuming that one table is the PK and the other is the FK with a UNIQUE constraint/index on the FK making it a 1-1 relationship.,

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are misunderstanding the way relationships in Access work.
I do guess also that you used the relationship manager.
What does it do? It tells Access which tables to show preferably in sub-forms and sub-tables to name just one feature, but it definitely does not synchronize the tables.

If you want to synchronize tables in a 1to1 relation, make sure that the linked fields are unique within each table (indexed), write a query to synchronize the tables (guess the query wizard has a template).
You could as well write a macro or use a form in case you want to synchronize the items individually.

In summary: you need to do the synchronisation by yourself.

On the other hand, if you really want to have the data synchronized and it is a 1to1 relation, then why split the data over two tables?

HTH, Y.

Comment: ***In summary: you need to do the synchronisation by yourself.***  Cascade update will do it if you have referential integrity enforced.

Comment: @xQbert, hoped to learn something new, so tried your advice right away in Access 2013. Couldn't see the synchronisation requested in the question above. The linked fields are synchronised, but no records are created in the linked table.

Comment: The question mentions noting about creating records in the linked table; only that the if the PK is updated, tables containing that Key as a foreign key in a different table are updated.  Watch the youtube video.  It shows exactly the situation where the parent PK is updated from 1 to 101 and the child records FKs are automatically updated to 101 as well.  But to be honest why ever change a PK? It should never be exposed to the user, and I can't imagine why I would need to update a PK in such a fashion.

Comment: Probably my misreading of "Or do I have to individually ADD each line? (btw there is 19,000+ records so far)"?

Comment: "But to be honest why ever change a PK? It should never be exposed to the user, and I can't imagine why I would need to update a PK in such a fashion." That's why I asked if a single table wouldn't make more sense. Cheers.